# How to correctly print μ by write_csv?

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

`write_csv()` in `readr` outputs μ as Âµ. How to correctly output μ using `write_csv()`?

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- tribble(~x, 'µ')
write_csv(x, 'test.csv')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write_csv()` will work correctly when the characters in tibble are in raw byte with UTF-8 Encoding.

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- tribble(~x, '\xb5')
Encoding(x$x) <- 'UTF-8'
write_csv(x, 'test.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the correct fileEncoding = UTF

```
write.csv(x, 'test.csv', fileEncoding = "UTF-16")
```